# How can I update a label on one form from another form in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I want to update label of `Form1` from `Form2`. So here's what I have:

```
// Form1
public string Label1
{
    get { return this.label1.Text; }
    set { this.label1.Text = value; }
}


// Form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.Label1 = this.textBox1.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```

So the above code doesn't work. However, when I add the following:

```
frm1.Show();
```

after

```
this.Close();
```

in Form2 code, the Form1 obviously is being opened again (two windows). But I want it to update in the same window so I suggest `this.Close()` is unnecessary.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `button1_Click` method, you're actually creating a *new* instance of `Form1` and setting the `Label1` property of that new instance. That explains why a *second* instance of `Form1` is being shown on the screen when you add `frm1.Show();`. If you look at that second copy carefully, you'll see that it's label displays the correct value, but your original copy of that form retains its original value.

Instead, I assume that what you want to do is set the `Label1` property for the *existing* instance of `Form1` that is already displayed on the screen. In order to do that, you're going to have to get a reference to that existing form object.

Thus, this becomes a simple question of "how do I pass data between two objects (forms)", which has been asked countless times here on Stack Overflow. See the answers to these related questions:

- [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c)
- [Passing values between two windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227016/passing-values-between-two-windows-forms)
- [C# beginner help, How do I pass a value from a child back to the parent form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form)
- [Send values from one form to another form in c# winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-winforms-application)

Answer (score 1):

Try using singleton design pattern for that as I think the problem is when you using new

```
public class Form1Singleton {

    private static final Form1Singleton INSTANCE = null; 
    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Form1Singleton () {
    }

    public static Form1Singleton getInstance() 
    {
       if(INSTANCE ==null)
            INSTANCE =new Form1Singleton();

        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Now you can use the form easily  only 1 form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
Form1Singleton frm1 = Form1Singleton.getInstance();

frm1.Label1 = this.textBox1.Text;     
this.Close(); 
}
```

I hope that solve your problem

BR,

Mohammed Thabet Zaky

Answer (score 0):

Most probably: What you actually do is create a brand new instance of `Form1` within the scope of `Form2`, while later in the control flow of your program another instance of `Form1` is created and shown. Of course, in such a case you can't expect your label to be set correctly.

The best would be to decouple `Form1` and `Form2` from each other and instead pass only data along the control flow of your program.

Answer (score 0):

When you say this.close that means all the values you set to that instance gets nullifies.

You can use [delegate](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mosessaur/winformsdelegates09042006094826am/winformsdelegates.aspx) here, to set form values.

Comment: Where in the posted code does `form1.close` appear? This does not explain the problem (s)he's experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

MVP pattern is good for this type of senario and also separate UI and business logic.

This thread is good reference:
[UI Design Pattern for Windows Forms (like MVVM for WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595469/ui-design-pattern-for-windows-forms-like-mvvm-for-wpf)